# How to trigger Android function in Javascript from within iframe in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I've `Android.close` method being exposed as JSBinding so that it can be called from JavaScript in webview to close it. However, I've an iframe that loads a sample page inside `index.html`, the webview renders. Calling the same method from within the iframe does not trigger it to close the webview.

What's the solution?

I've tried following ways with no luck:

1. `window.parent.window.Android.close()` from within iframe.
2. Stored `window.AndroidClose = Android.close` in a variable inside the `index.html` and called it from within the iframe as `window.parent.window.AndroidClose()`.
3. Tried `postMessage` API to do a message passing between iframe and the `index.html` by sending a message and calling it inside the callback as `window.addEventListener('message', function() { Android.close(); }, false);`

Comment: Is close annotated with @JavascriptInterface?

Comment: Yes, I could call it from `index.html` but not from within iframe.

Comment: Just covering all my bases, since a project I work on makes use of javascript to native communication:

(Assuming you've created a WebSettings object) is setJavaScriptEnabled true?

Did you add a JavascriptInterface to the webview containing your annotated method?

Comment: Yes. Webview loads -> index.html renders -> iframe loads -> test.html.
`Android.close()` from index.html works but not from test.html.